Multiple groups based on conditions in SQL
There is one scenario where I am struggling to implement a logic in Teradata, I have a table as shown below.
My key columns are COLA and COLB, now the logic which I need to implement is that within group of COLA and COLB, if my count(distinct COLC) > 1, then I need to look into COLD within that group (COLA and COLB), and then do a different grouping by including COLC.
Now I need to find the group (now here when I say group we need to consider COLA, COLB and COLC) which have value for COLD with R004. In this scenario we can see that the group 12345,asdf,1 have COLD with value R004, so basically I need to ignore that complete group. So here the records with COLA value 12345, COLB value asdf and COLC value 1 will be eliminated in the output.
The key point here is this condition needs to be checked only when this count(distinct COLC) > 1 within the group of COL A and COL B, otherwise rest of the records needs to be in the output as it is.
I tried to use count(distinct) over by partition, but it looks like Teradata doesn't support this function. I'm wondering if there is any way I can achieve this with a single query functions?



COLA
COLB
COLC
COLD
CO
COLF
COLG
COLH




12345
asdf
1
R004
r
tr




12345
asdf
1
R009
r
tr




12345
asdf
1
R0101
r
tr




12345
asdf
1
R453
r
tr




12345
asdf
1
R5678
r
tr




12345
asdf
4
R009
r
tr




12345
asdf
4
R0101
r
tr




12345
asdf
4
R453
r
tr




12345
asdf
4
R5678
r
tr




12345
asdf
4
R5434
r
tr




32145
frte
1
R004
r
tr




32145
frte
1
R453
r
tr




32145
frte
1
R5678
r
tr




32145
frte
1
R5434
r
tr




45678
erwq
4
R4879
r
tr




45678
erwq
4
R5654
r
tr




45678
erwq
4
R5323
r
tr





The expected output should be like this:



COLA
COLB
COLC
COLD
CO
COLF
COLG
COLH




12345
asdf
4
R009
r
tr




12345
asdf
4
R0101
r
tr




12345
asdf
4
R453
r
tr




12345
asdf
4
R5678
r
tr




12345
asdf
4
R5434
r
tr




32145
frte
1
R004
r
tr




32145
frte
1
R453
r
tr




32145
frte
1
R5678
r
tr




32145
frte
1
R5434
r
tr




45678
erwq
4
R4879
r
tr




45678
erwq
4
R5654
r
tr




45678
erwq
4
R5323
r
tr






Without digging into your detailed logic: count(distinct col) > 1 can easily be translated to a simple min(col) <> max(col)

I manage to write the query and its working as expected. You will be able to see couple of tables extra, but the table which I given is a join of those two tables in SUBQUERY
SELECT 
     COLA, 
        COLB, 
        COLC
        
FROM (
    SELECT 
        COLA, 
        COLB, 
        COLC, 
        COLD,
        max(COLC) over (partition by COLA, COLB) max_index,
            min(COLC) over (partition by COLA, COLB) min_index,
        SUM(CASE WHEN COLD = 'R004' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY COLA, COLB, COLC) AS R004Flag
    FROM 
        (sel COLA, COLB,COLC,COLD from 
TAB1  INNER JOIN  TAB2
    ON  TAB1.ID = TAB2.ID 
AND TAB1.GId = 'R60'  )aa
) AS subquery
WHERE 
    case when (max_index <> min_index AND  R004Flag =0) then 1  
         When (max_index = min_index AND  (R004Flag =1 or R004Flag =0)) then 1
else 0 end=1


Small remark, avoiding the CASE might help the optimizer: WHERE (max_index <> min_index AND  R004Flag =0) OR (max_index = min_index AND  (R004Flag =1 or R004Flag =0)). And the WHERE-conditions could be moved to a QUALIFY without need for subquery
